# Regular Expression in xml image filename

Tags: c#, regex, xml

I want to have a code, that will search an image filename in the xml and find it in the images folder. I already used regex.

```
xptrImages = Regex.Matches(abridgedXMLContent, "(?<=<xp t=\").+?(?=\"/>)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
if (xptrImages != null)
                    {
                        foreach (Match gif in xptrImages)
                        {
                            if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(jobPath_ill, gif.Value)))
                            {
                                ErrorModel errorModel12 = new ErrorModel()
                                {
                                    ErrorMessage = string.Concat("No actual image found -- ", gif.Value),
                                    LineData = string.Concat("<xp t=", gif.Value, "/>")
                                };
                                err.Add(errorModel12);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

But my regular expression didn't return me an message if they didn't find the image filename in xml. is my reg exp correct. I'm targeting the image001.gif in the xml see below.

```
<p><xp t="image001.gif"/></p>
```

Comment: Use a parser instead of regex.

Comment: can you show me sample code..

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thanks.. I should study this, I'm really not that famillar system.xml.

Answer (score 0):

XPath is the way to go, yes - you could just retrieve //xp/@t

If you want to use regex though, be certain you escape the forward slash / in your regex. Example at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iN3xL9/1).

```
(?<=<xp t=\").+?(?=\"\/>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            string input = "<p><xp t=\"image001.gif\"/></p>";
            string pattern = "=\"(?'filename'[^\\.]+\\.(gif|jpg))\"";

            string filename = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Groups["filename"].Value;​
```